# Discrepancy in P/E ratio of stocks in Robinhood app?

Tags: price-earnings-ratio, robinhood, earnings-per-share

The current price of the Amazon stock is $1673. The latest EPS ratio was $6.04 for Q4 2018. So, the P/E ratio should be `$1673/$6.04 ~ 279`. But the robinhood app says the P/E ratio of Amazon is 83. What am I missing?

Comment: Stack exchange didn't let me post screenshots of the app, because apparently I am still too new here..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The EPS of Amazon for the last quarter of 2018 was $6.05. However, the P/E ratio is calculated using an *annual* number for earnings. Amazon’s earnings for 2018 was $20.14. ([Source](https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/AMZN/amazon/eps-earnings-per-share-diluted))

$1673 / $20.14 = 83.07

Answer (score 1):

The price per earnings is the price divided by the yearly earnings.
The Earnings per Share of quarter 4 should could be a quarter of the total earnings. Add all of the Earnings per share for 4 quarters, and use that as the Earnings.